# Tab completion of "../" in zsh

Tags: zsh, directory, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

In bash, I can use tab-completion to move one directory up and descend down again another path. For example, suppose I'm in `$HOME/folder1`, and I want to `cd` to `$HOME/folder2`. `$HOME` only has the two child directories `folder1` and `folder2`.

In bash, I could just type

```
cd ..[TAB]f[TAB]2
```

and would end up in `$HOME/folder2`. In my fresh zsh installation, pressing `cd ..[TAB]` produces a list of those child directories of `$HOME/folder1` which have two `.` in their name.

Is there a simple way to get the behaviour I'm used to? Or is there something even easier to achieve what I want in zsh?

Comment: Yeah, (re)learn to hit `/` (slash) instead of TAB for a directory delimiter.  You've already typed `..` the `/` is right next to `.` on every keyboard I've seen.

Comment: Down voting a new user with an honest question isn't cool. No reason for that! I see that he tried explaining the best he could.

Comment: @RickyBeam You should take a look at non-english keyboards then ;) I'm using a German keyboard, and there the `/` is very inconveniently located at `SHIFT+7`.

Comment: I have a UK and Korean(?) keyboard, and they both use a standard QWERTY layout.  DEC and SUN keyboards can be a little weird, but I don't have them at hand.  I'd reprogram my keyboard if I had to hit shift-7 to get a slash.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc` and ..[TAB] will complete to ../ as per `bash`.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
```